# Chash on .AddExtensions only when start app with windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium chromeDriver on Vb.net.
Using Windows 7 i have a strange problem.
If i set the app for start with Windows start, i got an crash app in this line:

```
.AddExtensions
```

The code is:

```
Dim options As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
options.AddExtensions("ExtensionFoo.crx")
```

But if i start the app manually once Windows has started all is running fine.
I have tryed to set a delay on app start, but doesn't work.
Anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can be due to chrome auto update... not sure.